# Investigate HTTP 406 Error code only on first call

Tags: spring, http, rest

I have a server which uses Spring to expose some RestServices. I have ~20 services which do almost always the same things : get, list, save...

Among all those services, I have ONE request that does not behave like the others :

```
@RequestMapping(value = {"/{id}"}, method = RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody
public Line get(@PathVariable(value = "id") int id) {
  return lineService.getById(id);
}
```

Problem :

- When I restart the server and call this particular request for the very first time, I get a 406 Error Code.
- After that, all other calls end in success, returning well-formed JSON with HTTP 200 code etc.

The Accept Headers of the request contains "application/json".

I tried to add this on the requestMapping :

```
produces="application/json"
```

It seems that somewhere, the server adapts the content/type of the reponse after the first fail but I definitely cannot understand where.

I tried with tomcat and jetty as backend server and I have the error on both.

Any ideas?

EDIT :

After further investigation, I detected this difference in tomcat logs. On the first call (HTTP 406), I can see this :

```
09:33:58.637 [http-bio-9090-exec-3] DEBUG o.s.o.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryUtils - Closing JPA EntityManager
09:33:58.637 [http-bio-9090-exec-3] DEBUG o.s.w.a.FixedContentNegotiationStrategy - Requested media types is application/json (based on default MediaType)
09:33:58.654 [http-bio-9090-exec-3] DEBUG o.s.w.s.m.m.a.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver - Resolving exception from handler [public com.mycompany.myproject.dto.MyClass com.mycompany.myproject.controller.patrimoine.LigneMobileController.get(int)]: org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotAcceptableException: Could not find acceptable representation
09:33:58.657 [http-bio-9090-exec-3] DEBUG o.s.w.s.m.a.ResponseStatusExceptionResolver - Resolving exception from handler [public com.mycompany.myproject.dto.MyClass com.mycompany.myproject.controller.patrimoine.LigneMobileController.get(int)]: org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotAcceptableException: Could not find acceptable representation
09:33:58.657 [http-bio-9090-exec-3] DEBUG o.s.w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver - Resolving exception from handler [public com.mycompany.myproject.dto.MyClass com.mycompany.myproject.controller.patrimoine.LigneMobileController.get(int)]: org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotAcceptableException: Could not find acceptable representation
09:33:58.657 [http-bio-9090-exec-3] DEBUG o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Null ModelAndView returned to DispatcherServlet with name 'springServlet': assuming HandlerAdapter completed request handling
09:33:58.657 [http-bio-9090-exec-3] DEBUG o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Successfully completed request
09:33:58.657 [http-bio-9090-exec-3] DEBUG o.s.s.w.a.ExceptionTranslationFilter - Chain processed normally
09:33:58.657 [http-bio-9090-exec-3] DEBUG o.s.s.w.c.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter - SecurityContextHolder now cleared, as request processing completed
```

On the second call, I can see this (differences start at 2nd line):

```
09:50:52.384 [http-bio-9090-exec-7] DEBUG o.s.o.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryUtils - Closing JPA EntityManager
09:50:52.385 [http-bio-9090-exec-7] DEBUG o.s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor - Written [com.mycompany.myproject.dto.patrimoine.mobile.ligne.LigneMobile@18949ad1] as "application/json;charset=UTF-8" using [org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter@32a64bcd]
09:50:52.385 [http-bio-9090-exec-7] DEBUG o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Null ModelAndView returned to DispatcherServlet with name 'springServlet': assuming HandlerAdapter completed request handling
09:50:52.385 [http-bio-9090-exec-7] DEBUG o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Successfully completed request
09:50:52.385 [http-bio-9090-exec-7] DEBUG o.s.s.w.a.ExceptionTranslationFilter - Chain processed normally
09:50:52.385 [http-bio-9090-exec-7] DEBUG o.s.s.w.c.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter - SecurityContextHolder now cleared, as request processing completed
```

So, in the first case, I get some HttpMediaTypeNotAcceptableException when trying to convert the object to JSON.

Comment: Why you wrote that you are using Jersey if the example has Spring annotations (not JAX-RS)? Could there be some misunderstanding of those technologies?

Comment: After a check on maven depdencies, that was an error : we don't use Jersey. I edited the question, thanks.

Comment: I think that 406 is about request AND response : it occurs when Content-Type of the response does not correspond to the "Accept Header" of the request, or I miss something? For the Spring handler mapping, the team and I are converging to this, still investigating.

Comment: I've deleted my comment - it was not correct. It is about the accept header. Sorry about incorrect info.

Comment: @adenoyelle which Spring version are you running?

Comment: I am using version 3.2.3.RELEASE

Comment: @adenoyelle try configuring content negotiation and setting favorPathExtention to false, see [Spring docs](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-config-content-negotiation)

Comment: Why in the first case Spring thinks that the method returns `com.mycompany.myproject.dto.MyClass`? Is it possible that there is conflicting handler mapping? Check bootstrap messages of Spring to see what handler mapping it loads.

Comment: Wow, there is something wrong in those logs... I am checking.

Comment: I am terribly sorry but the log was not accurate. I actually copy-pasted the log of a request which was executed just after the get() in case of success(The application basically get the object then does another request to get some objects related to it). I edited the question to put the accurate piece of log.

Answer (score 1):

I would start by firing up something like [Fiddler](http://fiddler2.com/) to see what bits are actually going over the wire.

Answer (score 1):

You say, that Accept Headers contains `application/json`. I would start investigation by sending request without specifying accepted content types. There should be some relevant clue in server response, when it's not constrained by specific content type. Web servers usually tend to return error page formatted as HTML if they encounter any error during processing the request. Content type is of course text/html in such case and therefore the real problem is obfuscated by 406 error.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to set a breakpoint on the first line of the controller method, i.e. `return lineService.getById(id);`?

I suspect that you will hit that line, but that there will be some initial error if you try to "step into" that method with the debugger. If my assumption is correct, somewhere an exception will be thrown, resulting in an html page with a stack trace. Next, you will see the 406 occur, because the html page has media type `application/html`, or similar which cannot be converted to `application/json`.

Comment: I tried to split this line in 2 parts `Line  line=lineService.getById(id)` and `return line;` an put a breakpoint to see the structure of the returned line. In both cases, the resulting `line` seems to be well-formed. The problem seems to occur when Spring tries to transform it to JSON.

Answer (score 0):

Given that you see this error only after you restart your server, makes me think that maybe this is related to lazy class loading.

Try using a servlet that initializes on server start (i.e. with a `load-on-startup` value of 1), that - in its `init` method - refers to all the classes involved in rendering `com.mycompany.myproject.dto.datagrid.LoadResult` to json?

Remember that you're trying to ensure that all the classes involved, are loaded by the ClassLoader before the request comes in.